# How to make custom field on Acc object available but do not display?

Tags: custom-field, account

I created a new custom field on the account object and this field should be hidden on all the pages but should be there on the HTML.

I just want to initialize this field by passing parameter in the url like `/001/e?custom_id='sdssd'`

Is there any way to do this without writing custom VF page?

Comment: Have you looked into Field Accessibility?

Comment: Tried that, It completely removes the field from the HTML..I want the field should be there on the HTML but not visible..

Answer (score 1):

If you are using chrome browser, you can create a quick plugin where the field is not visible on the page(hidden) but the field can be saved when user clicks on save button.

Comment: Kalyan, Can you please explain more on this? I didn't get you. Here is my requirement: When user clicks on `New Account` button on the VF page, I want to pass a value to the account field in url but on the page it should be hidden..

Comment: My understanding is that this page that you want the field to be hidden is a standard layout page.  Before last year, you could have done this by writing a jQuery/Javascript on the home page component to hide the fields.  Since this feature is no longer available, if your users are using chrome browser, you can create a add-on that has this jQuery to hide the field when the page loads.  That way, you are still populating the value thru the url and is hidden on the page.  HTH.